# Function to check if each vector element decreases by 1 or more

Tags: r, if-statement, user-defined-functions, logical-operators

My task is to write a function to check if, at most, a 1-stage drop per year is an appropriate assumption for my dataset. In other words, I want to return a logic indictor of `FALSE` if where the average drop in score is more than 1 per year and a logic indicator of `TRUE` when the average drop in score is 1 per year.

A sample of the data set is:

```
score <- matrix(c(8,rep(NA,6),7,NA,NA,3,NA,9,9,
 6, 6, NA, NA,9,9,8,NA,NA,7,rep(NA,4),
rep(NA,9),8,NA,5,7,rep(NA,1),
rep(NA,8),7,3,rep(NA,4),
rep(NA,5),9,rep(NA,3),7,NA,NA,6,6),nrow=5,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(score) <- paste("Year",2003:2016,sep="")
rownames(score) <- 1:5
score
```

I'm quite at a loss on where to start, but here is my attempt before inserting into a function:

```
ifelse(score[score[i] - score[1+i,]=1], TRUE, FALSE)
```

Unsurprisingly, this gives an error message:

`Error: unexpected '=' in "ifelse(score[score[i] - score[1+i,]="`

Here is another attempt, which when ran yields the error message:

```
Error in 1:n : argument of length 0

check2 = function(x) {
    n = ncol(x)
    for(i in 1:n)
        if(x[x[1,] - x[1+i,] == 1]){
        return(TRUE)
    }else{
        return(FALSE)
    }
}
```

UPDATE: The desired result is a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each row of data.

Comment: Do you need `==` instead? The single `=` is for *assignment*, not comparison.

Comment: You are right, that is an error I made. Thank you. Changing that, my error message says `i` is not found. I edited my question to include an attempt at a function with a for loop. Please excuse my inexperience if these are basic questions.

Comment: `score` is a matrix, you should be using double-index extraction, ala `x[i,j]` instead of just `x[i]`; the latter is technically legal but incomprehensible to me logically. Furthermore, you have (1) years with no data, and (2) years with just 1 datum, and it is not clear what output you are expecting from this. Please update your question with expected results, such as: F, ?, ?, ?, ?, T, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, F, F. (The ?'s are b/c you haven't identified rules for increases or not-2+ data.)

Comment: Ok, I have updated. The desired result is a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each row of data.

Comment: You misunderstood. Your rules are incomplete, so please provide the literal answer for each row (I previously thought columns, my bad).